# Is there a way to change iOS7.1 'button shapes' setting in the simulator?

Tags: ios, accessibility, ios7.1

Since iOS 7.1 there is a *button shapes* option among the accessibility settings.
As far as I can tell it is not available in the iOS simulator.
Is this true or did I miss something?

Comment: It's true. File an enhancement request with Apple to get it added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While there is no public API, and you should indeed open an enhancement request with Apple at https://bugreport.apple.com, here is some Leo magic for you:

https://gist.github.com/LeoNatan/9532361

Put this anywhere in your code and voilà, shapes are enabled. Delete to disable shapes. **Remember not to ship app using this code as it will be rejected by Apple.**

Comment: Thank you. The Leo magic works like a charm (after replacing the first line with `#import <objc/runtime.h>`). Also I filed a report at the suggested site (16324384).

Comment: @lupz Good to hear. The `@import` syntax is the new Xcode modules syntax.

Comment: To avoid accidental inclusion in shipping code, add "#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR #endif" block around the methods in this class.

Answer (score 0):

It's available in the simulator now for iOS 9.0, Xcode 7.0 in the settings app -> general -> accessibility -> button shapes.